# NGINX redirect old https domain to new non-https

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

Yesterday I have changed my domain name hat was foobar.tk and it was running over https. For now, on my new domain foobar.eu I does not have ssl.

I have succeed with redireting using CNAME records while I am not using https, but somehow I cannot redirect https://www.example.tk to http://www.example.eu Chrome says that connection was resset. Firefox says that content cannot be validated,...

For redirection I am using these lines:

```
server {
    listen 443; (note: i have tried with *:443, *:443 ssl, 443 ssl)
    server_name www.example.tk; (i have tried with orwithout www.)
    return 301 http://www.example.eu$request_uri; (i have tried to redir to $host also where then cname will handle the issue)
}
```

What works:

http://www.example.tk -> http://www.example.eu using CNAME (and all other subdomains)

What is not working:

https://www.example.tk -> http://www.example.eu

I still can certificates backed-up, so if it can help in some way please tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up SSL on Nginx you should use [`ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.tk;
    ssl_certificate         /path/to/certificate; #.crt, .cert, .cer, or .pem file
    ssl_certificate_key     /path/to/private/key;
    return 301 http://www.example.eu$request_uri;
}
```

These two files you can get from your Certificate Authority.

Also you should add `ssl` parameter to `listen` directive.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for later response, I wil try this today, and will accept if worked